# Add Time to live to property to my cache

Tags: java, gemfire, cache-expiration, spring-data-gemfire

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <util:properties id="gemfire-props">
        <prop key="log-level">warning</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <gfe:cache properties-ref="gemfire-props" />

    <gfe:local-region id="LocalRegion1">
        <gfe:cache-listener>
            <bean
                class="com.mycompany.util.LoggingCacheListener" />
        </gfe:cache-listener>
    </gfe:local-region>

</beans>
```

How can we add a time to live property for the LocalRegion1 or the cache defined as above? I would like to completely refresh my cache every 24 hrs and get new data from server. Im using a local cache, which get some data from a server and stores locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a time-to-live on a region, by adding a region-ttl node, as stated below:

```
<gfe:local-region id="LocalRegion1">
    <gfe:region-ttl timeout="${local.region1.ttl}" action="DESTROY"/>
    <gfe:cache-listener>
        <bean
            class="com.mycompany.util.LoggingCacheListener" />
    </gfe:cache-listener>
</gfe:local-region>
```

In this example, you can set the time-to-live in seconds by using a property named `local.region1.ttl`. Of course you can always rename that property or use a literal instead (60 seconds):

```
<gfe:region-ttl timeout="60" action="DESTROY"/>
```

Note that the timer will be reset every time you update / add an entry to the region.